# Uploading Image from Android to Node

Tags: android, node.js, base64, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images to my node server via Android Studio. However the image file always seems to be corrupt on the server. I am able to take and preview the picture in Android but not able to store it on my server.

**Here is my server code**

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var base64Data = req.rawBody;
    fs.writeFile("test.jpg",base64Data,'base64',function(err,written){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("file Succesfully written ");    
            cloudinary.uploader.upload("test.jpg", function (image) {
                if(image !== undefined) {

                     res.json({link: image.secure_url}).end();
                     console.log("url = " , image.secure_url);
                 //   fs.unlink(ImageFile);
                } else console.log.error("Error uploading to Cloudinary, ", image);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is my front end code I use to convert my bitmap to an encoded Base64 String.**

```
final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(fileArray.get(i));
```

Here is a log of what encodedString holds after being set. Obviously the full value is not displayed.

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
                                                                          AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
                                                                          AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAMgA+gDASIA
                                                                          AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
```

However on my backend it is displayed as this

```
2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%0AAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH%2F2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%0AAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH%2FwAARCAMgA%2BgDASIA%0AAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQ
```

Comment: hint: What you are seeing on the backend is a urlencoded version of the encodedString from the frontend.

Comment: What would my work around to this be? @AlexGittemeier

Comment: If you get it url encoded then you should url decode it.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much @greenapps ! How can I mark your comment as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get it url encoded then you should url decode it.

Comment: Wonderful! :). For anyone who wants to decode on node.js. Use the following. var test = unescape(value_to_decode);

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream imageStream;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);//uri is the image URI
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                    byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.NO_WRAP);//encodedImage is your image string

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks bro but my issue is with the backend not parsing the image correctly. However, I got it figured out! Thanks